# Java dependency inversion Principe , как не нарушать и писать гибкий код

Tags: java, dependency-injection

Как мы все знаем dependency inversion говорит о том , что модули верхнего уровня не должны зависеть от модулей нижнего уровня , и оба должны зависеть от абстракций , кто более подробно расскажет что это означает и как писать код который не нарушает dependency inversion и его можно масштабировать , допустим я хочу написать метод для валидации Email и как теперь его вызвать там где мне нужно ? Создавать экземпляр класса в котором этот метод ? Ну это вроде как нарушает dependency Inversion , с помощью интерфейсов и абстракций ? Тогда это сколько же интерфейсов будет или абстрактных классов , с помощью статиков (утилит) ну как бы тоже не самое хорошее решение , и вот как быть ??

Answer (score 0):

у вас есть какой-то класс, где вам надо сделать валидацию емейла.
вы создаете интерфейс `IEmailValidation` с методом `validate()` который на вход принимает `String` и возвращается `boolean`
и создаете класс `EmailValidationImpl` наследник от `IEmailValidation`
в вашем классе, где вы хотите использовать валидацию, вы создаете объект типа `IEmailValidation`, но сам объект будет `EmailValidationImpl`

именно таким образом и соблюдается это правило SOLID.
теперь вы можете создавать различные вариации реализации `IEmailValidation`. и при этом ваш класс, где вам надо будет валидировать емейл, никак не будет меняться. потому что он **не зависит от модуля нижнего уровня. он зависит от абстракции**.

**Тогда это сколько же интерфейсов будет или абстрактных классов?**
много. практически на каждый класс, который является архитектурным, а не незаменяемой утилитой.

Comment: Т.е мы все таки когда нам нужен метод мы создаём экземпляр класса который имплементирует наш интерфейс ? И второй вопрос , лучше стараться под каждый метод , создавать свой интерфейс ?

Comment: да. мы создаем экземпляр класса. но вызываем его абстрактно `IEmailValidation valdator = new EmailValidationImpl();`. если использовать библиотеки для DI раскроется в идеальном ключе. чем больше у вас отдельных интерфейсов и их реализаций, тем более гибкая система у вас будет. `Single Responsibility Principle`

Comment: т.е dependency inversion лучше использовать в связке с dependency injection ? Либо тем же самым spring , а разве когда мы создаём IEmailValidation validator = new EmailValidationImpl , мы не зависим от него ?

Comment: @Артур я Андроидщик, но слышал что в Spring'е отличный DI (но сам судить не могу). нет, мы не зависим от `EmailValidationImpl`. мы зависим от `IEmailValidation`. а какая будет реализация `EmailValidationImpl` или `EmailValidationImplTwo` или `EmailValidationImplNewCoolRefactor` - это уже неважно нашему классу который хочет отдать строку и получить "валидная ли она?". если подключить DI, то вы вообще не увидите, какой объект вам будет даваться. вы будете говорить "DI, я хочу получить `IEmailValidation`" и он вам его вернет. а что именно за класс будет - вы не будете знать и не должны.

Comment: @Артур из этой же логики и выходит правило SOLID `Барбары Лисков`. я его всегда описываю как "папу-котика можно попросить сходить в туалет. тогда папа-котик идет, садиться в лоток и справляет свои дела. результат в лотке. сын-котик тоже умеет ходить в туалет. но он делает свои дела в коридоре. затем берет совок, веник и убирает все это в лоток. результат в лотке. интерфейс котик - умеет ходить в тулает. результат в лотке. его реализации - папа-котик и сын-котик".)

Comment: @Артур т.е. интерфейс - это желаемое поведение. мы на вход даем `такие-то` данные. на выходе получаем `эти данные`. а вот "как это будет сделано? кем это будет сделано?" - вообще не забота классов верхнего уровня.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо , а можешь показать пожалуйста нормальную реализацию dependency injection (через java код без сторонних библиотек ) а то их много

Comment: @Артур к сожалению не подскажу. недавно слышал на собеседовании вопрос "как бы вы реализовали DI без библиотек", и даже не знал, что ответить) библиотеки DI дают слишком много плюшек, которые упрощают жизнь и я даже не представляю, как их написать самому.